# Solution Verification: Calculate the minimal polynomial of the following number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Calculate the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 e^{{2\pi i}/ 3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This question is from my quiz (now over) and I want to verify my solution.

$\sqrt2$ and $ e^{{2\pi i} /3}$ are LI so i need to find the minimal polynomials separately. Also F[a,b]= F[ab] for this case. Now the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2$ is $x^ -2$ and minimal polynomial of $e^{{2\pi i}/3 }$ is $x^3-1$ but $ x^3 -1 = (x-1)(x^2 +x+1)$ and x-1 $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ so the minimal polynomial is $x^2+x+1$.

So, the minimal polynomial of the given number is $ x^2 -2 \times x^2 +x +1$.

Am i right?

Comment: Minimal polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. (Why?) That suggests you are not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us just write $$a=bc, b=\sqrt{2},c=\exp(2\pi i/3)$$ then we have $$b^2=2,c^2+c+1=0$$ Observe that $c^2$ is also a root of $x^2+x+1$ and $a^2=2c^2$. Thus we get $$(a^2/2)^2+(a^2/2)+1=0$$ and thus $a$ is a root of $x^4+2x^2+4$.

Next observe that $a$ is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb {Q} $ (why?) and hence $x^4+2x^2+4$ is the desired minimal polynomial.

Alternatively you may prove that $$p(x)= x^4+2x^2+4$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb {Q} $ and deduce that it is the desired polynomial. Note that if $\alpha $ is root of $p(x) $ then so is $-\alpha$. Further since all coefficients of $p(x) $ are positive its root can't be positive and hence by earlier observation it can't have negative roots as well. Thus we don't any linear factor of $p(x) $ over $\mathbb {Q} $. If there is a quadratic factor over $\mathbb{Q} $ we must have $$x^4+2x^2+4=(x^2+rx+s)(x^2-rx+t)$$ where $r, s, t$ are integers. This means that $$s+t-r^2=2,rt-rs=0,st=4$$ which does not have a solution in integers (check this).

---

Your approach is assuming that if $a, b$ are roots of $f(x), g(x) $ then $ab$ is root of $f(x) g(x) $. No that's not the case. The set of roots of $f(x)g(x) $ is the union of set of roots of $f(x) $ and $g(x) $.  In a similar manner you *should not assume* that $a+b$ is a root of $f(x) +g(x) $.

Comment: @Singh Why did you took a=bc in first line? There must be some reason of taking it. Can you please explain?

Comment: @No-One: the number in your question is $a$ and it is a product of two algebraic numbers $b=\sqrt {2}$ and $c=\exp(2\pi i/3)$. So this is based on your question.

Comment: @Singh It's a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, $(x^2-2)(x^2+x+1)$ *does not* vanish for $x=\sqrt{2}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$.
 Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$, which is a primitive third root of unity. It fulfulls $\omega^2+1=-\omega$, so $(\omega^2+1)^2 = \omega^2$ and $\omega^4+\omega^2+1 = 0$, so $\alpha = \omega\sqrt{2}$ is a root of $\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+1$ or $x^4+2x^2+4$. This is the minimal polynomial since

$$ 4=\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\omega):\mathbb{Q}\right]=\underbrace{\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\right]}_{2\text{ by complex extension}}\cdot\underbrace{\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}\right]}_{2}. $$

As an alternative, let us consider $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-2,y^2+y+1)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, with a basis given by $1,x,y,xy$. Let us represent the powers of $xy$:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline n & 1 & x & y & xy \\
\hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline 2 & -2 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
\hline 3 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 4 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
\hline\end{array}$$

The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\-2&0&-2&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&4&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ has rank $4$ and by expressing the fifth row as a linear combination of the previous ones we get $(xy)^4 = -2(xy)^2-4$.